# Laravel 5 issue with wherePivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working with Laravel 5 and I am having issue getting `->wherePivot()` to work on a Many-to-Many relationship. When I `dd()` the SQL it looks like Eloquent is looking for records in the pivot table with a `pose_state`.`pose_id` is null`.

I am hoping it is a simple error and not a bug. Any ideas are appreciated.

#### Database Structure

**pose**

```
id
name
type
```

**state**

```
id
name
machine_name
```

**pose_state**

```
pose_id
state_id
status
```

#### Models

**Pose**

```
<?php namespace App;
use DB;
use App\State;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pose extends Model {

  public function states()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\State')
                  ->withPivot('status_id')
                  ->withTimestamps();
  }
  public function scopeWithPendingReviews()
  {
      return $this->states()
                  ->wherePivot('status_id',10);
  }
}
```

**State**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class State extends Model {

    public function poses()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Pose')
                  ->withPivot('status_id')
                  ->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

**PosesController function**

```
public function listPosesForReview(){
    $poses = Pose::withPendingReviews()->get();
    dd($poses->toArray() );
}
```

**SQL**

```
select 
  `states`.*, `pose_state`.`pose_id` as `pivot_pose_id`,
  `pose_state`.`state_id` as `pivot_state_id`, 
  `pose_state`.`status_id` as `pivot_status_id`, 
  `pose_state`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, 
  `pose_state`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from 
  `states` inner join `pose_state` on `states`.`id` = `pose_state`.`state_id` 
where 
  `pose_state`.`pose_id` is null and `pose_state`.`status_id` = ?
```

## EDIT

When I updated my code to removing the scope it worked. Thanks @Deefour for putting me on the right path! Maybe scope has something else to that I am missing.

```
public function pendingReviews()
{
  return $this->states()
              ->wherePivot('status_id','=', 10);
}
```

## YET ANOTHER EDIT

I finally got this to work. The solution above was giving me duplicate entries. No idea why this works, but it does, so I will stick with it.

```
public function scopeWithStatusCode($query, $tag)
{
  $query->with(['states' => function($q) use ($tag)
            {
              $q->wherePivot('status_id','=', $tag);
            }])
        ->whereHas('states',function($q) use ($tag)
            {
              $q->where('status_id', $tag);
            });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your implementation of `scopeWithPendingReviews()` is an abuse of the intended use of scopes.

A scope should be thought of as a reusable set of conditions to append to an existing query, even if that query is simply

```
SomeModel::newQuery()
```

The idea is that a pre-existing query would be further refined (read: 'scoped') by the conditions within the scope method, not to generate a new query, and definitely not to generate a new query based on an associated model.

By default, the first and only argument passed to a scope method is the query builder instance itself.

Your scope implementation on your `Pose` model was really a query against the `states` table as soon as you did this

```
$this->states()
```

This is why your SQL appears as it does. It's also a clear indicator you're misusing scopes. A scope might instead look like this

```
public function scopeWithPendingReviews($query) {
  $query->join('pose_state', 'poses.id', '=', 'pose_state.pose.id')
        ->where('status_id', 10);
}
```

Unlike your new `pendingReviews()` method which is returning a query based on the `State` model, this scope will refine a query on the `Pose` model.

**Now** you can use your scope as you originally intended.

```
$poses = Pose::withPendingReviews();
```

which could be translated into the more verbose

```
$poses = Pose::newQuery()->withPendingReviews();
```

Notice also the scope above doesn't return a value. It's accepting the existing query builder object and adding onto it.

The other answer to this question is filled with misinformation.

1. You cannot use `wherePivot()` as is claims.
2. Your use of `withTimestamps()` is not at all related to your problem
3. You don't have to do any "custom work" to get timestamps working. Adding the `withTimestamps()` call as you did is all that is needed. Just make sure you have a `created_at` and `updated_at` column in your join table.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought something like this is what you would use scopes for? What would you use here instead? I changed the code per your suggestion and I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Deefour - Unfortunately your answer about the usage of `wherePivot` is incorrect. In the snippet of the source you linked it shows that `wherePivot` is pretty much just a proxy to the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::where` method, which allows the syntax that OP is trying. Refer to the [source here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/38439a5a5bd5c3e8f9aa8ba3e252d71300d3110c/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L451)

Comment: @Scopey ...  `func_num_args()` there will return **`4`** in this case, not `2` as **FOUR** arguments are passed into the `where()`.

Comment: It turns out the scopeWithPendingReviews() was the issue. I don't know why, so if you have any ideas, it would be great to hear your thoughts.

Comment: So I set up the Pose model with your scope suggestion and it is pulling multiple rows of the Pose table. I was hope to set up a scope where it would pull one Pose with a related set of States that have the status_id of 10. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly in your last edit confuses you? I'd be willing to bet the SQL between your scope and the one we were working on previously is very similar. I'd suggest sticking with the simpler scope from yesterday and work on adding something like `->distinct()` to get a unique list of Poses.

Comment: @deefour Scopey is correct. Making your statement bold doesn't make you more correct. [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/22c06c504067cc52787f9fc4b04de4e496442212/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L456) is why you're wrong. You can't be lazy if you're going to be so wrong :(

Comment: @deefour Scopey is correct again. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships. Seriously, come on. Timestamps are not maintained for pivot tables.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're attacking me. You are more than welcome to edit my answer to suggest corrections. You might want to read the page you linked a bit closer regarding pivot table timestamps, specifically this bit: **If you want your pivot table to have automatically maintained created_at and updated_at timestamps, use the withTimestamps method on the relationship definition**

Answer (score 2):

I think that your implementation of scopes is fine, the problem I see is just a typo. Your schema shows that the field is called `status` but your where condition is referring to a `status_id`

Try:

```
->wherePivot('status', 10);
```

Also, the `withTimestamps()` method is causing issues. You don't have timestamps in your schema for the pivot (as I can see) so you shouldn't be putting these in the your relation definitions as it's trying to fetch the timestamps relating to when the relation was created/updated. You can do this if you set up your pivot table schema to have the timestamp fields, but I think you'll have to do some custom work to get the timestamps to save properly.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (Laravel 5.3):

```
$task = App\Models\PricingTask::find(1);
$task->products()->wherePivot('taggable_type', 'product')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have this problem (return no results) if the column you are using in `wherePivot` hasn't been added to `withPivot`.