# Getting records where pivot [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How can I get all records by relation.

I have like this:

```
    return Conversation::with('messages')
    ->get();
```

So I need to return all convrsation where in pivot table I have `user_id` 1

it would be ideal if there is some function like this:

```
->wherePivot('user_conversation.user_id',1)
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551413/laravel-5-issue-with-wherepivot

Comment: It will not query main modal it will query just relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Conversation` has a `belongsToMany` relationship setup with `User`, you can use the `whereHas()` method to constrain the conversation query with the user relationship.

```
$id = 1;
return Converstaion::with('messages')->whereHas('users', function ($userQuery) use ($id) {
        $userQuery->where('id', $id);
    })
    ->get();
```

This will only return conversations that are related to the user with the id of 1. You can read more about `whereHas()` and other useful methods under [querying relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

Another option, if you already have the user loaded, is to just return that user's conversations:

```
$user = User::find(1);

return $user->conversations()->with('messages')->get();
```